# Creating a downloading bar for an updating exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar, pyinstaller, download

I am trying to include a downloading bar for my updating script, but I cannot quite workout how to do this. Strangely, at the moment there is a downloading bar is present during debug:

https://github.com/JMSwag/PyUpdater/blob/master/pyupdater/client/downloader.py

```
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:{'total': 11128343, 'downloaded': 16385, 'status': 'downloading', 'percent_complete': '0.1', 'time': '05:36'}
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Block size: 43553
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:{'total': 11128343, 'downloaded': 49153, 'status': 'downloading', 'percent_complete': '0.4', 'time': '04:42'}
DEBUG:pyupdater.client.downloader:Block size: 43515
```

I've had a look at their downloader.py and attempted to create a progress bar of sorts.  Any ideas on how this might be achieved?
At the moment a bar is displayed (finished), but no progressing bar to show how long it has to go.

```
def check_for_update():
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar()
    for i in bar(range(100)):
        time.sleep(0.0)

    def cb(status):
        zz = status['downloaded'] * 100.0 / status['total']

        zz = bar.update(status.the_dwad)

        print(zz)

    import os
    import sys
    from contextlib import contextmanager


    import sys
    import os
    stdout_save = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    client = Client(ClientConfig(), refresh=True, progress_hooks=[cb], headers={'basic_auth': 'brofewfefwefewef:EKAXsWkdt5H6yJEmtexN'})
```

It would seem: def cb(status): is not being called

I've also included full script and other information if desired to replicate [here](https://github.com/tysondogerz/Pyupdater-and-bitbucket-V3/blob/master/Steps%20to%20replicate)

Comment: Can you point me to the web address/pip keyword for building the `client_config` library?

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston Take a look at - https://github.com/JMSwag/PyUpdater/blob/master/pyupdater/client/downloader.py self.progress_hooks = kwargs.get('progress_hooks', []) . Is this what you mean?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify; I'm trying to run the full script you linked to, but the script fails when trying to `import  client_config`. I'm trying to determine which library this is and where I can go to build it so I can run your code.

Comment: @DanielR.Livingston Please check  out: https://github.com/tysondogerz/Pyupdater-and-bitbucket-V3/blob/master/Steps%20to%20replicate .  And my other files, I have included the files I used as well

Comment: I should mention that for your main.py I would use - https://github.com/tysondogerz/Pyupdater-and-bitbucket-V3/blob/master/main.py rather than example in step by step as this has a monkey patch which fixes urllib3 bug.  As you will get error 400 otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues with the code.

- You shouldn't have debugging log enabled, else that would hamper with the progress bar
- You didn't start the progress bar
- You had a error in progress bar callback `status.the_dwad`
- The code may not run well in a IDE as progressbar has some issues with it, so you should run it in a terminal

[image: Progress bar working]

Below is the code that I ran

```
import urllib3.poolmanager

orig_urlopen = urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.urlopen


def new_urlopen(self, method, url, redirect=True, **kw):
    if "s3.amazonaws.com" in url and 'authorization' in self.headers:
        self.headers.pop('authorization')
    return orig_urlopen(self, method, url, redirect, **kw)


urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager.urlopen = new_urlopen

import logging

# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

import http.client as http_client

# http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

import logging
from selenium import webdriver

# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

from client_config import ClientConfig
from pyupdater.client import Client, AppUpdate

import progressbar
import sys

bar = None


def check_for_update():

    def cb(status):
        global bar

        if bar is None:
            bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(widgets=[progressbar.Percentage(), progressbar.Bar()], fd=sys.stdout).start()
        zz = float(status['percent_complete'])

        bar.update(zz)

    # sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

    client = Client(ClientConfig(), refresh=True,
                    headers={'basic_auth': 'brofewfefwefewef:EKAXsWkdt5H6yJEmtexN'})

    client.platform = "win"
    app_update = client.update_check(ClientConfig.APP_NAME, ClientConfig.APP_VERSION, channel='stable')
    if app_update is not None:
        app_update.progress_hooks.append(cb)
        if app_update.download():
            if isinstance(app_update, AppUpdate):
                app_update.extract_restart()
                return True
            else:
                app_update.extract()
                return True
    return False


def main():
    print('Current version is ', ClientConfig.APP_VERSION)
    if check_for_update():
        print('there\'s a new update :D')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why does it print authorise 4 times and prints two download bars I wonder https://pastebin.com/YrdBqft5

Comment: There is a key download then the manifest update download, then a actual download. That is why you see the progressbar download twice. If you need to avoid that. You should set the callback function just before the `app_update.download()`

Comment: Could you show in your example how this might be done?

Comment: Updated the code. Also the header print is a bug in the pyudater, it shouldn't be there idealy

Comment: I see.  It stilll seems to displays N/A%   as well as download bar unfortunately - https://pastebin.com/Zfqyehyh

Comment: I don't see that issue when i run it on mac, so you need to debug on your machine

Comment: Last question :).  How Can I display bar only if above a certain size e.g: (if block_size > 100 * 1024)  https://github.com/tysondogerz/Pyupdater-and-bitbucket-V3/blob/master/main.py